# How to read high-level storage variable from inline assembly?

Tags: contract-development, storage, assembly

This code does not compile:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    uint256 public foo = 314;

    function myFunction() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        assembly {
            result := foo
        }
    }
}
```

This error is thrown:

> TypeError: only local variables are supported. To access storage variables, use the ".slot" and ".offset" suffixes.

I modified my code like this:

```
result := foo.slot
```

But the result I got was "1" instead of "314". How can I get access to this storage variable in inline assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Access to External Variables, Functions and Libraries](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/assembly.html#access-to-external-variables-functions-and-libraries) section in the docs.

The solution is to use the `sload` function and pass the slot as the only argument:

```
assembly {
    result := sload(foo.slot)
}
```

Caveats:

- Be careful if the value you're reading does not have a span of exactly 256 bits (e.g. `address`). You cannot assume that the bits not part of the encoding will be zero.
- For dynamic data types like arrays, you have to use `.offset` and `.length` besides `.slot`.

Comment: It is simple. But, `result` memory variable didn't return as real value. It is `result` memory variable initialize value `1` in `constructor()`, when I assign like this and console log with hardhat log result like this `5973652239065808857055946470512512878469198127164779725056`. Why? Compiler version is `0.8.4`. Thank you for interest.