# How to load the first 4 bytes from a bytes calldata var?

Tags: solidity, abi, assembly, bytes, function-selector

It is common for calldata to be encoded as `bytes calldata` when developing contracts in Solidity.

I need to extract the function selector from such a bytes var. What's the best way to load the first 4 bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function func(bytes calldata data) external {
    bytes4 selector = bytes4(data[:4]);
}
```

Also works for calldata, if you don't feel like using Yul

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your answer. I will mark this as the accepted answer because this is a more secure way of accessing the first 4 bytes (see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-proxy/issues/50)).

Answer (score 7):

### Jan 2023

As per the bug report in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-proxy/issues/50), it is more secure to use Ryan Sea's answer, which uses high-level Solidity to access the first 4 bytes in the `data` bytes array.

### Oct 2021

Most gas-efficient way is to use [inline assembly](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/):

```
function foo(bytes calldata data) external payable {
    bytes4 selector;
    assembly {
        selector := calldataload(data.offset)
    }
    // ...
}
```

The offset suffix is a [special property](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108025/how-to-read-high-level-storage-variable-from-inline-assembly) that we need to use in inline assembly to be able to read high-level storage variables.