# meaning of `slot` property in Yul?

Tags: solidity, storage, yul

I was reading through the implementation of ERC721A Upgradable's ERC721AStorage.sol and found [this function](https://github.com/chiru-labs/ERC721A-Upgradeable/blob/main/contracts/ERC721AStorage.sol#L54)

```
function layout() internal pure returns (Layout storage l) {
    bytes32 slot = STORAGE_SLOT;
    assembly {
        l.slot := slot
    }
}
```

I'm specifically wondering about `l.slot`. I'm guessing the `slot` property has a special meaning in [Yul](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html) associated with *the storage slot*, but I don't really know if that's correct. Where can I learn about how this works?  I read through https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html and didn't see anything specific to this, but maybe I missed something?

[EDIT]:  [This example](https://remix.ethereum.org/?#code=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&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7%20commit.e28d00a7.js) demonstrates using the slot to store and retrieve, but I still haven't found any docs or a good explanation of this.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/108025/99409) helped shed some light on `.slot` for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slot is a word used to describe the location of stack and storage in Yul. You can take a look at this resource to learn more about how slot works:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/assembly.html#memory-safety